# squirrelsql doesn't like query_to_xml

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, squirrel-sql

I am using an SQL that includes query_to_xml:

```
select query_to_xml('select 1+1 answer', true, true, '') as_xml;
```

When any SQL with `query_to_xml` is executed in Squirrel SQL it will result in:

```
|      as_xml        |
+--------------------+
|<UnknownType (2009)>|
```

With the same JDBC driver, credentials and a Java class the SQL will result in the expected XML output:

```
|                          as_xml                            | 
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| <row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">|
|                                                            |
|   <answer>2</answer>                                       |
| </row>                                                     |
```

I can execute other functions in Squirrel and they will respond, like `select version()`.

Is this a known feature in Squirrel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the latest squirrel client, Go to File, Global Preferences-> Data Type Controls, check the box under Unknown DataTypes section.
Rerun the query, it might work.

Comment: Yes, did work! 10 months later and you solved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the text option output for SQL results. It works if you change to the tabular output. Go to the Session menu and click "Session Properties". On the "General" tab under "Output" change "SQL Results" from Text to Table and rerun the query. You may need to close the existing results tabs first.

If this fixes it please add a bug report so that it can be fixed in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but changing between Table and Text doesn't help (Table is default BTW). Instead I'll get the output in a slightly different format: 
    <UnknownType (2,009)>

Comment: What version of SQuirreL are you using? I'm using a recent snapshot snapshot-20150211_2036.

Comment: 3.6 Standard from 20150128 (Jan 28) and latest snapshot 20150221_2246 gives the same result.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is a difference in the JDBC driver/server. I'm running Postgresql 9.3.5. The JDBC driver reports itself as PostgreSQL 9.2 JDBC3 (build 1002).

When I issue your query the meta data tab reports the column type as '1111' which is "xml    1111 [OTHER]' according to the Data Types tab, not 2009

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Like I wrote in the main post, I am running exactly the same driver (and DB) with a Java application and the query_to_xml function works. It's not a critical defect as I still can run the query in psql for testing, but it is a bit annoying...